# Constant beep when recording sound

Tags: audio, usb-audio, microphone, arecord

I am using an external sound card with my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. I have already disabled the default bcm2835 sound card. I have checked that the my external sound card is active. I have turned up mic and capture volume using alsamixer. When I try to record sound using `arecord`, the sound output file has a constant beeping sound and no other sound is picked up. I tried playing music to see if the mic captures music sound in the background and it doesn't. I tried only speaking to the mic and keeping it close while talking and it didn't work. I am not sure what's the issue here.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I have tried a new sound card but still same problem. To add better context, I am adding some the details of the card and how I am trying to record:

```
arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Here's how I am trying to record:

```
arecord -r 44100 -D hw:1,0 -f S16_LE -t wav -v testR1.wav
```

I have also tried `pulseaudio`:

```
parecord --channels=1 -d alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00.analog-mono filename.wav**strong text**
```

Same result unfortunately!

Comment: Have you tried your USB sound-card with another computer?  
Does the microphone work there?  
Is it really a microphone input or line-in?
There are different type of microphones. Are you sure the microphone matches that input?

Comment: Here's what I have tried so far:

I have tried 2 different soundcard with https://www.bdshop.com/clip-microphone-boya-by-m1 this microphone. I used two sound cards to check: 

1. https://www.tvc-mall.com/details/steelseries-siberia-5hv2-usb-7-1-channel-external-sound-card-desktop-notebook-black-skupca-520a.html

2. http://live-tech.in/sc01.php

From what I gathered, both have microphone inputs. 

I tried using it with my laptop using `arecord` and `parecord` using the specific card `hw:1,0` but, same problem.

Comment: Then the microphone does not match the input. Try another one. Usually it is simpler to use an USB microphone to avoid such pitfalls.

Comment: Try looking through the `config.txt` file. There may be an option which stops audio problems. Yesterday when trying to fix my Raspberry Pi's HDMI problems I saw a few options which had to do with audio.